# sre.findall() in parsing web page

Tags: python, parsing, findall

I'm using urllib2 and sre in Python to parse data from aprs.fi so I can use weather data in  some real time high altitude balloon code I'm working on. The parsing code is pretty simple:

```
import urllib2
import sre

APRStracking = urllib2.urlopen( "http://api.aprs.fi/api/get?name=KD8REX&what=loc&apikey=42457.M4AFa3hdkXG31&format=xml" )

APRSxml = APRStracking.read()

latitude = sre.findall( '<la.*>(.*)</la.*>', APRSxml )
print latitude
```

The data I'm trying to parse is an XML, which looks like:

```
<xml>
   <command>get</command>
   <result>ok</result>
   <what>loc</what>
   <found>1</found>
   <entries>
      <entry>
         <name>KD8REX</name>
         <type>l</type>
         <time>1339339410</time>
         <lasttime>1339339410</lasttime>
         <lat>41.95550</lat>
         <lng>-83.65567</lng>
         <altitude>2204.62</altitude>
         <course>15</course>
         <speed>15</speed>
         <symbol>/O</symbol>
         <srccall>KD8REX</srccall>
         <dstcall>APT311</dstcall>
         <status>UofM H.A.S. - Go Blue!</status>
         <status_lasttime>1339339600</status_lasttime>
         <path>WIDE1-1,WIDE3-3,qAR,W8SGZ</path>
      </entry>
   </entries>
</xml>
```

I'm not terribly familiar with Python, but my understanding of ser.findall() is that it looks through APRSxml looking for any strings that match the regular expression, and then appends whatever is between the parentheses in list "latitude." So, in this example, the two values that match the regular expression are "lasttime" and "lat." However, when I run this code it only outputs the `<lat>` value, not `<lasttime>`. Frankly, that's all I really need for my code to work, but out of curiosity, I'd appreciate if anyone could tell me why it isn't behaving as expected. Thanks.

Comment: It produces the expected output for me.  Also, why are you using `sre` instead of `re`?

Comment: I actually just realized I'm using a deprecated module haha... But regardless after changing to re I'm still only getting the lat value.

Comment: You should check that the value of APRSxml is what you think it is (by `print`ing it, maybe).  As I said, when I run your code `findall` returns two values.

Comment: I confirmed after printing that <lasttime> and <lat> are both there. And strangely enough, I changed the regular expression to '<la..+>(,*)</la..+>', thinking that there was no way lat would match it, while lasttime should. But printing latitude still gave me the <lat> value. This seems to contradict everything I know about regular expressions.

Comment: I first tried the regex copy/pasting the data from the question and had the same results as @BrenBarn. But running the code including the retrieval of the data actually gives the results ricewhite reports.

Comment: Okay, so that means the problem has nothing to with the regular expression, but with the data returned by urllib.

Comment: I see the problem.  The problem is that the file does not contain the data you pasted.  It contains the same XML with no whitespace.  This is obviously vital when parsing using regular expressions.  The lesson is, paste the data you are using, not the data you wish you were using.

Answer (score 4):

Looking at the `form` parameter, I noticed that you could specify `form=xml`. I changed it to `json` and look at that, you get JSON!

```
{
  "command":"get",
  "result":"ok",
  "what":"loc",
  "found":1,
  "entries":[
    {
      "name":"KD8REX",
      "type":"l",
      "time":"1339339410",
      "lasttime":"1339339410",
      "lat":"41.95550",
      "lng":"-83.65567",
      "altitude":"2204.62",
      "course":"15",
      "speed":"15",
      "symbol":"\/O",
      "srccall":"KD8REX",
      "dstcall":"APT311",
      "status":"UofM H.A.S. - Go Blue!",
      "status_lasttime":"1339339600",
      "path":"WIDE1-1,WIDE3-3,qAR,W8SGZ"
    }
  ]
}
```

It's easy to parse. Easier than XML:

```
import urllib2, json

url = 'http://api.aprs.fi/api/get?name=KD8REX&what=loc&apikey=42457.M4AFa3hdkXG31&format=json'
data = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

for entry in data['entries']:
  print 'Latitude:', entry['lat']
```

It's really easy to work with. `data` is just a Python dictionary.

Comment: Best possible solution to the problem at hand. I can't give this enough +1's.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the greedy stars to lazy matches (*?).

```
>>> re.findall('<la.*?>(.*?)</la.*?>', APRSxml )
['1339339410', '41.95550']
```

What currently happens is that `<la.*>` matches everything from the first `la` to the last occurence of `>` that still allows the rest of the expression to find a match. So, `<la.*>` matches

```
<lasttime>1339339410</lasttime><lat>
```

Explaining why the lasttime value isn't reported.

Comment: This should not be the case unless the DOTALL flag is set.

Comment: @BrenBarn: The xml returned by urllib doesn't contain newlines.

Comment: You're right, the original post did not accurately say what the data was.

Answer (score 0):

Try this non-greedy version:

```
latitude = re.findall('<la.*?>(.*?)</la.*?', APRSxml)
>>> print latitude
['1339339410', '41.95550']
```

But if you want "latitude" why not just do this?

```
latitude = re.findall('<lat>(.*?)<', APRSxml)
```

Comment: Ahhhhh, that did the trick, thank you! I know just matching <lat> would be sufficient for what I needed but I'm not too familiar with Python, and I figure a good way to learn is just to fool around with the language. This was just a little quirk that I just couldn't figure out.

Comment: If you are looking for a better solution to parsing XML with regular expressions (definitely **not** recommended) take a look at what [Blender discovered](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11200728/21945) for you.

Answer (score 0):

Python includes an easy-to-use XML parser that is ideally suited to this task:

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse
>>> APRStracking = urllib2.urlopen("http://api.aprs.fi/api/get?name=KD8REX&what=loc&apikey=42457.M4AFa3hdkXG31&format=xml")
>>> tree = parse(APRStracking)
>>> tree.find('entries/entry/lat').text
'41.95550'
```